# JavaFX export to jar. No main class found

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, javafx-2

I am obviously missing something. If i create a new javafx 2.0 project in eclipse and export the project to a jar, then run the command in a command prompt window of

```
Java -jar programname.jar
```

I get an error saying no main class found. Why?

**EDIT**
I have tried to run

```
java -cp . -jar programname.jar
```

But this returns an error saying

no main manifest attribute, in programname.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appears i must of deleted an important line in my Main file which is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Now it works

Answer (score 0):

try:
 `java -cp -jar . programname.jar`

Comment: I am sorry, this question has been revised.

Answer (score 0):

The command doesn't know where to find main class. 
Try with -cp option:

```
java -cp . -jar programname.jar
```

It sets search for main in classes in current directory. 
Then You can write bash/bat script to run this jar.

Comment: Is there no way to export the program as a jar in a working state so it can be run with the original command?

Answer (score 0):

Try to export jar as runnable jar and it will asks you to give main class.

I hope it will work for you.